# Why is a graph an ordered pair?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

From [the source of all knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29)

> a graph is an ordered pair G = (V, E) comprising a set V of vertices
>   or nodes together with a set E of edges or lines, which are 2-element
>   subsets of V

Why must it be an ordered pair? It seems irrelevant if you mention V or E first. Must V come first since E is made up of V?

Comment: No, it really is irrelevant.

Comment: I've seen a lot of books define it with ordered pairs.

Comment: That's for convenience, to some extent. If I say I have a graph $(A, B)$, you know that $A$ is the vertices and $B$ is the edges. Unordered pairs are less natural.

Comment: Another thing you're missing is that the question is wrong. Graph isn't a pair. It *can be described by* a pair. There are plenty of other ways to describe a graph.

Comment: The question is correct, it is perfectly in order to define a graph to be an ordered pair $(V,E)$ as stated. You are free to use alternatives, but this does not invalidate the definition.

Answer (score -1):

You don't even need a pair. A graph may be defined simply as a set $G$ of singleton or two-element sets. The set of vertices is then $V=\bigcup G$, while $E$ is the set of two-element members of $G$, and $G\setminus E$ is the set of isolated vertices. However, this will not do if you need to specify [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_%28graph_theory%29), which are edges that connect a vertex to itself, or multiple edges, although these types of edge would be regarded as illegitimate or irrelevant in the mainstream of graph theory. And of course ordered pairs are needed to define a *directed* graph.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The graph would only consist of $E$? And $E$ would be the set of what exactly? (Not edges, if you are allowing singletons. And disallowing singletons would mean you can't have isolated vertices.) And then $E$ is a collection of singletons/two element sets of what kind of objects, if you haven't defined vertices except as a union of the sets in $E$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers : Sorry, my use of the letter $E$ was confusing. (See edit.) This definition of $G$ as a mixed bag of isolated vertices and edges does not claim to be elegant. Rather, it is minimal in a certain set-theoretic sense.

Comment: The use of $E$ as a letter is not what made it confusing. I think it would be a very problematic and circular definition (for example, the sets contained in $G$ are sets of what?), and would interfere with a lot of the nice things that can be done with graphs when they are defined properly (see for example the definition of the Kneser graph).

Comment: @MorganRodgers : The elements of $G$ are one- and two-element sets whose union is $V$, the set of vertices. The isolated vertices are the elements of the one-element sets, and the edges are represented by the two-element sets, each comprising two vertices connected by an edge. In this formulation, the (nontrivial) Kneser graph $\mathrm{KG}_{n,k}$, having no isolated vertices, is represented, just by $E$, its set of edges, with $V=\bigcup E$. The elements of $E$ are the sets of two disjoint $k$-element subsets of the basic $n$-element set (say) $B=\bigcup V$.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes when you transform graphs to solve problems in computer science, you need to make the edges of the original graph into the vertices of the new graph (G = (V, E) gets transformed into G' = (E, E')) and then you need to define what the new edges are.

An example would be you have a map and you need to see if there's a way to get from point point A to point B where you only take right turns. $ E' = \{(u, v) \to (v, w) | u, v, w  \in V \land (u, v) \in E \land (v, w) \in E \land \text{u to v to w form a right turn} \} $